# Find the i-th greatest element

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, recurrence

I want to use a Divide-and-Conquer procedure for the computation of the  i-th  greatest element at a row of integers and analyze the asymptotic time complexity of the algorithm.

```
Algorithm ith(A,low,high){
   q=partition(A,low,high);
   if (high-i+1==q) return A[q];
   else if (high-i+1<q) ith(A,low,q-1);
   else ith(A,q+1,high);
}
```

Is it right? If so, how could we find its time complexity?

The time complexity is described by the following recurrence relation:

T(n)=T(n-q)+T(q-1)+Θ(n)

But how can we solve this recurrence relation, without knowing the value of q?

Or is there an algorithm with less time complexity that computes the i-th greatest element at a row of integers?

Comment: What do you mean "the time complexity"? Average, worst-case, something else? Then the correct recurrence relation can be determined. What you have for the recurrence relation is currently wrong whatever version of "time complexity" you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the [quick select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm (which finds the `i-th` smallest element rather than `i-th`greatest element). It has a running time of `O(n^2)`in the worst case, and `O(n)` in the average case.

To see the worst case, assume you are searching for the `nth` largest element, and it happens that the algorithm always picks `q` to be the largest element in the remaining range. so you will be calling the `ith` function `n` times. In addition the partition subroutine takes `O(n)` so the total running time is `O(n^2)`.

To understand the average case analysis , check the explanation given by professor Tim Roughgarden [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMyTo73ibwM&spfreload=10).